# How to add a properties file to a Java Spring project?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I defined a properties file to be used in a Spring (not Spring Boot) Java project to populate the values of a HashMap. I tested the class that reads the properties with a JUnit Test class and the values are read correctly. The problem occurs when I run the build with Maven, as it appears that this file I added to the project is not copied when generating the war file and I get the error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/csv-convertion.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at it.egeos.aware.dm.orchestrator.config.PropertyFileReader.read(PropertyFileReader.java:15)
    at it.egeos.aware.dm.orchestrator.batch.base.tasklets.GeoMesaIngestFileTasklet.createSftFile(GeoMesaIngestFileTasklet.java:239)
    at it.egeos.aware.dm.orchestrator.batch.base.tasklets.GeoMesaIngestFileTasklet.execute(GeoMesaIngestFileTasklet.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor315.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy190.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:272)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.FlowState.handle(FlowState.java:55)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean$DelegateState.handle(SimpleFlowFactoryBean.java:207)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.FlowState.handle(FlowState.java:55)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.xml.SimpleFlowFactoryBean$DelegateState.handle(SimpleFlowFactoryBean.java:207)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.job.JobStep.doExecute(JobStep.java:117)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.doHandle(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:104)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.AbstractPartitionHandler.handle(AbstractPartitionHandler.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:106)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I have tried including the file in the pom.xml in this way, but the program execution crashes when a stream is executed that involves reading properties. It does not give an error in that case, the program simply gets stuck and does not move forward. It does get unstuck, however, if I make a call to a different API.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Finally, I show how I read the property file in the class I defined.

```
Map<String, String> properties = PropertyFileReader.read("src/main/resources/csv-convertion.properties");
```

Comment: There is no `src/main/resources`... `src/main/resources`, like `src/main/java` is the root of the classpath. Just use `/csv-convertion.properties` as the file to read. Remove the path stuff. Next to that when you package up the application this will fail to load as well, as the `/csv-convertion.properties` isn't a file but a packed resource and cannot be read with a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a Spring project and trying to read a properties file, there's a standard way to do this using the `@PropertySource` annotation in your configuration class. Also, it's good practice to use the Environment and `@Value` annotations for reading properties in a Spring application.

Here's how you can modify your code to use Spring's approach:

Move your properties file (e.g., csv-convertion.properties) into the src/main/resources directory.

Create a configuration class where you load the properties file using the `@PropertySource` annotation:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:csv-convertion.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    // You can add more configurations if needed
}
```

Autowire the Environment and use the `@Value` annotation to get the properties in your class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class PropertyFileReader {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public Map<String, String> read() {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        
        // Example: Reading a property named 'example.property'
        String exampleProperty = 
        environment.getProperty("example.property");
        properties.put("example.property", exampleProperty);

        // Add more properties as needed

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Now, your properties file will be loaded automatically, and you can access the properties using `environment.getProperty("property.key").`

Ensure that your Maven dependencies include the required Spring framework libraries. If not, you can add them to your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I have some points for mention with this question,

**1.You should move the properties file:**

Move your `csv-convertion.properties` file from `src/main/java` to `src/main/resources` in your project, because this is the stranded location for resources in Maven projects.

**2.Update the resources configuration in POM:**

**3.Update PropertyFileReader:**

```
public static Map<String, String> read(String fileName) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try (InputStream input = PropertyFileReader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
        if (input == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Property file '" + fileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }
        properties.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // Handle the exception
    }

    // Convert properties to a Map if you needed
    Map<String, String> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
        propertyMap.put(key, properties.getProperty(key));
    }

    return propertyMap;
}
```

**4.And then you should verify Maven Build:**

Keep your mind, that maven is correctly building your project. you can build the project and generate the WAR file by using bellow command.

```
mvn clean install
```

**5.Now you can check your generated WAR file:**

After the build, you can check your WAR file check your contents of the generated WAR file.